# Using Ionic 3 Side-Menu with ion-slider (like Slack)

Tags: ionic3, slack

I'm trying to create an Ionic application that has a side-menu with a slider implemented. I have tried implementing the code in the app.html page using this code:

```
<ion-menu class="" [content]="content" id="menu-basic">
   <ion-slides pager>
      <ion-slide>
         <h1>Page 1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
         <h1>Page</h1>
      </ion-slide>
   </ion-slides>
</ion-menu>
```

But the issue I'm having is:

1. The pager at the bottom does not show
2. It doesn't slide from one slide to another

[Slack Side-Menu with slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqpib.png)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! Please check your code to ensure this is not a typo issue - I see that your ion-slides closing tag is wrong (should be </ion-slides>)

Comment: Thank you for the response. That was an oversight when I was writing the question. I'm using the correct closing tag i my project

Comment: ok I fixed it in your question. Personally I don't know the answe, but I feel like "swiping" action in side menu is reserved for open/close of menu. I am not sure it will be easy to implement slack like approach. WOuld you consider segment approach?

Comment: Hi I'm trying to build a slack-like sidemenu as you do in ionic but couldn't find a solution. did you find a solution? @SeyiB

Comment: This is definitely possible, please see my answer here: [Is it possible to use slides in ionic sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398114/is-it-possible-to-use-slides-in-ionic-sidebar/56814812)

Comment: @Brownoxford perfect! Thank you